# How to extract file from a .7z archive?

Tags: archive

I am trying to extract an iso of a gamecube game from a .7z file, but it wont work. Usually, I'd have WinRAR in Windows, but Ubuntu 14.04 isn't Windows.

Comment: Usually, I'd have 7zip in Windows. :D

Answer (score 4):

`7zip` is good for this and it integrates with the archive manager.

1. Install `p7zip` (and some add-ons to make sure you can open all formats)

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install p7zip p7zip-full p7zip-rar
   ```

Try opening the `.7z` archive again.

Comment: 7zip didnt seem to install. Its not showing in my apps list or opening that archive.

Comment: you may have a damaged archive, did the download come with a md5 sum or what error does archive manager show when you try to open?

Comment: No, I'm saying I don't think 7 zip installed, even though I ran the sudo command.

Comment: It says an error occurred while loading tue archive.

Comment: try the command line http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2125792 this says it may work with a command something like `7z e file.7z`

Comment: the command didnt seem to work. i forgot to mention (in case it makes a difference) im using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

You just need to install p7zip-full.

```
$sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Then extract package using: `7z x YOUR_FILE.7z`

**Example:**

```
$ ls
MyDir.7z

$ 7z x MyDir.7z

7-Zip [64] 15.14 : Copyright (c) 1999-2015 Igor Pavlov : 2015-12-31
p7zip Version 15.14.1 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz (806E9),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 335 bytes (1 KiB)

Extracting archive: MyDir.7z

Path = MyDir.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 335
Headers Size = 231
Method = LZMA2:16
Solid = +
Blocks = 1

Everything is Ok

Folders: 2
Files: 6
Size:       57024
Compressed: 335

$ ls
MyDir  MyDir.7z
```

The option "x" in 7zip preserves original directory structure.